# Pascal how to count the number of letters in a word?

Tags: char, pascal

Previously, the program counted the total number of letters and words in a string. Now I'm trying to make it so that it determines how many words with an even number of letters. Precisely character by character. Tell me how to finish.

```
program test;
var
  c : char;
  i : integer;
  numOfChar : integer;
  rem : integer;
begin
  i := 1;
  numOfChar := 0;
  rem := 0;
  c := ' ';
  writeln('Enter your string');
  read(c);
  
  while (c <> #13) and (c <> #10) do
  begin
    if c <> ' ' then inc(numOfChar)
    else inc(i);

    rem := numOfChar mod 2;
    read(c);     
  end;

  writeln('count of words: ', i);
  writeln('count of chars: ', numOfChar);
  writeln('rem: ', rem)
end.
```

Here is the code that I didn't finish.

Comment: Use "not odd()" to test if a number is even.

Comment: It seems to me there is a logic error in your code. Enter five spaces and <enter>, it will show five words entered! A space alone is not reliable. Introduce a variable, say `inWord: boolean` and initialize it to `false`. When user enters char <> space, set it `true` and increment char counter. When user enters char = space and `inWord = true`, set it `false` and increment `words`. At this point you can also check char counter being even or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to count words, you need to know when spaces are meaningful and when they *aren't*. Consider for example a string `'  hello world '`.

If you go into your loop over the string with a boolean named `in_word` set to false. We'll set it to true only when we detect a non-space character. We also have integer values `word_count` and `word_length`. Both are set to `0`. We'll increment `word_count` when `in_word` is true and we detect a space.

```
Char:        ' '
in_word:     false
word_count:  0
word_length: 0

Char:        ' '
in_word:     false
word_count:  0
word_length: 0

Char:        'h'
in_word:     false -> true
word_count:  0
word_length: 1

Char:        'e'
in_word:     true
word_count:  0
word_length: 2

Char:        'l'
in_word:     true
word_count:  0
word_length: 3

Char:        'l'
in_word:     true
word_count:  0
word_length: 4

Char:        'o'
in_word:     true
word_count:  0
word_length: 5

Char:        ' '
in_word:     false
word_count:  1
word_length: 0

Char:        'w'
in_word:     false -> true
word_count:  1
word_length: 1

Char:        'o'
in_word:     true
word_count:  1
word_length: 2

Char:        'r'
in_word:     true
word_count:  1
word_length: 3

Char:        'l'
in_word:     true
word_count:  1
word_length: 4

Char:        'd'
in_word:     true
word_count:  1
word_length: 5

Char:        ' '
in_word:     false
word_count:  2
word_length: 0
```

```
begin
  in_word := false;
  word_count := 0;
  word_length := 0;

  for i := 1 to length (input) do
  begin
    if in_word && input[i] = ' ' then
      begin ... end
    else if in_word then
      begin ... end
    else if input[i] = ' ' then
      begin ... end
    else
      begin ... end
  end
```

Now, can you modify this set of steps so it increments a `five_letter_words` variable whenever a five letter word is encountered?

Comment: Chris, I understood your idea. But I can't complete the code you wrote. For me it is very difficult at the moment. Can you please help in more detail?